# COUNTIF(FILTER(range;condition);criteria) issue in Google Speadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I've a strange result which I cannot explain.
The spreadsheet looks like this (I simplify the data as it's a part of larger sheet):

```
   A | B
-----+---
 1 X | Y
 2   |
 3   |
 4 1 |
 5 1 |
 6 1 |
 7 1 |
 8 1 |
 9 1 |
10 1 |
11 1 |
12 1 |
13 1 |
14   |
...and so empty rows till the end of the sheet.
```

Cell B2 contains formula:

```
=COUNTIF(filter(B4:B;$A4:$A = B4:B);"<>0")
```

Cell B3 contains formula:

```
=COUNTIF(filter(B4:B13;$A4:$A13 = B4:B13);"<>0")
```

What I expected to get is `0` in both `B2` and `B3` cells. Instead of that I receive `0` in `B2` and `1` in `B3`.
The formulas suppose to count number of same non-empty values in column (`B2`) or part of the column (`B3`).

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason that this gives 1:

```
=countif(na(),"<>0")
```

The filter in B3 gives no results, so you get "#N/A". When you feed this into COUNTIF, you get 1.

The filter in B2 does give some results (because it succeeds for all the blank cells in cols A & B). But the results are all blanks so you get a count of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach that I had is [this one](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qvVtnIqXBHg_acbbzK2Emc1au9kZ3_Hj3JCbvKxGQXI/edit?usp=sharing).

Basically it uses the following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula({"Count [Erik]";IF(B2:B="","",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B&"",QUERY({MyTable!B2:B&"",MyTable!C2:C},"Select Col1, COUNT(Col2) Where Col1 Is Not Null And Col2 = 'CriteriaA' Group By Col1"),2,FALSE)))})
```

(credits to Erik Tyler)